# how i read a variable from file?

Tags: c, file

This is the part of adding a new client. The problem is when I add 2 clients as an example and I close the program,
when I open it again the id will be 1.
I want to know how can I read the last id from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define nombre_de_clients 50
client cl;
client c[nombre_de_clients];
typedef struct date{
    int j,m,a;
} date;
typedef struct client{
    int id;
    char nom [30];
    char prenom [30];
    date date_nais;
    char  adresse[30] ;
    char tel [30];
} client;

void ajouter(){
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("client.txt","a+");
    printf("donnez le nom \n");
    scanf("%s",&c[cl.id].nom);
    printf("donnez le prenom:");
    scanf("%s",&c[cl.id].prenom);
    printf("donnez l'adresse:");
    scanf("%s",&c[cl.id].adresse);
    printf("donnez num de tel:");
    scanf("%s",&c[cl.id].tel);
    printf("donnez la date de naissance jj mm aaaa:");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&c[cl.id].date_nais.j,&c[cl.id].date_nais.m,&c[cl.id].date_nais.a);
    fprintf(f,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d/%d/%d\n%d",c[cl.id].nom,c[cl.id].prenom,c[cl.id].adresse,c[cl.id].tel,c[cl.id].date_nais.j,c[cl.id].date_nais.m,c[cl.id].date_nais.a,cl.id);
    fclose(f);
    cl.id++;
    printf("sucess\n");
}

int main(){
    int a;
    cl.id=1;
    do {
        printf("                    *------------- menu --------------*\n");
        printf("                    |  ajouter un client   :1         |\n");
        printf("                    |  supprimer un client :2         |\n");
        printf("                    |  rechercher un client:3         |\n");
        printf("                    |  modifer un client   :4         |\n");
        printf("                    |  gestion de comptes  :5         |\n");
        printf("                    |  quitter le programme:6         |\n");
        printf("                    *---------------------------------*\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        switch(a){
        case(1):

        if(cl.id>nombre_de_clients){
            printf("nombre de client maximal\n");break;}
            ajouter();break;
        }
    }while(a!=6);
    return 0;
}
```

I am still a beginner.
I hope you understand my question and you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no `cl` or `c` formally defined anywhere in this code, it therefore stands no chance to compile, much less run to your claim results. How you copy/pasted source verbatim and managed to omit those variables mid-source is something I'll ponder for awhile.

Comment: "i want to know how i read the last id from the file". It's not clear what you are asking. There's nothing in the code shown that reads anything from the file. To get the `id` you need to open the file and read all the records to count the number of existing clients.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry i forget to write it
i fixed it now
there is more then 600 line the code 
i can put it all here 
i copy just the part that i have problem in it

Comment: @kaylum i know
thats the problem i dont know how to read just the id from the file

Comment: You can't easily read just the id. Instead of `fprintf` you can `fscanf` to read back the whole record including the id.

Comment: @kaylum and if i read everything how i can just get the id from it

Comment: I told you. Use `fscanf` to read into each variable. Just like you are using `fprintf` to write out the variables, `fscanf` can be used to read the data back into variables.